# Get the name and values of second member of cluster made at stage1(contains two members only) of heatmaply given the name of one of the members

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, heatmaply

I have a data frame S=[rows x cols] containing samples s such that rownames tell the names of the samples and colnames tell the features of the respective samples.
In this data frame, i have inserted one test sample t1. Now i want to extract the name and values of that particular sample "s" which is similar or twin of t1.
For this purpose i have used heatmaply() which plots hierarchical clustering. Observing this plot, i can see a cluster made at stage 1(of iterative hierarchical clustering process ) which contains only two members, one is my test sample t1 and the other member is its almost twin or almost similar sample.
Now i want to extract only that twin or sample s from the cluster made at stage 1 that was similar to my test sample t1 and nothing else. Please guide me in this regard.

I know a little about the hclust and dist functions. The problem with dist is that it provides too much information and i cant think of anyway of how to extract the twin of my test sample t1 from the dist matrix. I know a little bit about cutree(). To my less knowledge, i think it can give the clusters, to which the members belong, depending on the value of argument k. So when the value of k changes, the members of the clusters change. i am wondering if i can exploit cutree so that i can get the stage 1 clusters(contain two members) and find the member that is similar to my test sample t1.
The values of hclust object particularly interested me. For example merge and order. Maybe someone can guide me more about it and i can use them to get the twin

I am sorry for this long post. I was trying to explain as clearly as possible in a concise manner and wanted to show that i have tried my knowledge but your experience is highly appreciated to solve this problem.